# Stuck Understanding Link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm really struggling to understand how to link_to a parent from with a loop.

My milestones belong_to my orders and my orders have many milestones.

In my orders index, I have a simple calendar (table_builder) which lists all my milestones.

```
<%= calendar_for @milestones, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |t| %>
  <%#= calendar_for(@orders, :year => 2009, :month => 1) do |t| %>    
    <%= t.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>
        <%= t.day(:day_method => :milestone_due) do |date, orders| %>
          <%= date.day %>
         <ul>
                <% for milestone in orders %>
                 <li><%= link_to milestone.name, order_path  %> </li> 
                <% end %>
         </ul>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

This all works swimmingly well but the link doesn't work - I need it to link back to the parent order, not the milestone. It's driving me crazy now!

In my controller, I tried putting:

```
 @milestoneorder = Order.find(params[:id])
```

But that says it can't find an order without an id.

I'm obviously missing something really basic here.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: You've been ending your posts with `thanks, Jenny` or something similar. This isn't necessary; every question/answer has your username below it, with a link back to your profile.

Comment: oops :) Sorry! Didn't realise, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `order_path` which `Order` to link back to:

```
<%= link_to milestone.name, order_path(milestone.order) %>
```

You could probably just shorten it to this too:

```
<%= link_to milestone.name, milestone.order %>
```

UPDATE

If there's a chance some of your milestones don't have orders, you can try something like this:

```
<% if milestone.order %>
  <%= link_to milestone.name, order_path(milestone.order) %>
<% else %>
  <%= milestone.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi again @dmarkow thanks for the fast reply. When I try the first method, I end up with: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"} ? Why is this so hard for me ;) !??!

Comment: I changed your first line to orders_path and I don't get any errors however it still redirects to localhost:3000/orders and not the show order path. Thanks

Comment: At least one of your milestones does not have an associated order (so `order_path` is being passed `nil` rather than an actual order, which is it is trying to match a route without an id.) See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, that makes sense. I've tried though and now it links to /orders.1 which isn't quite right..

Comment: @Jenny make sure you're using `order_path`, NOT `orders_path` (plural)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have a route setup for order.

In the `routes.rb` file

```
resources :orders
```

or if you do, you aren't passing in an `id` for the order.

```
link_to "link text", order_url(:id => @order)
link_to "link text", order_url(@order) # <== shortened
```

lastly, the problem may be that order is nil.  If it is nil, you will also get the 'can't find route' error.

## UPDATE

```
<% orders.each do |order| %>
    <li><%= link_to milestone.name, order_path(order)  %> </li> 
<% end %>
```

## UPDATE 2

The problem is in the names.  I think that you are getting get milestones from t.day not orders.

```
<%= t.day(:day_method => :milestone_due) do |date, milestones| %>
    <%= date.day %>
     <ul>
            <% for milestone in milestones %>
             <li><%= link_to milestone.name, order_path(:id => milestone.order_id)  %> </li> 
            <% end %>
     </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @natedavisolds My routes are already set up: resources :orders do
     resources :comments, :technicals, :milestones
  end Will try your suggestion now

Comment: The second update gives me the correct order id, however there's a dot in the path, not a /

Comment: Hmmm... I thought there was a belongs_to relationship.  Maybe I misunderstood. Well I hope it helped you.